# Problem after android Volley update 1.2.0

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-volley

```
StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL_LOGIN, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    if(response.equalsIgnoreCase("logged in successfully")){
                        Intent intent1 = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, Home.class);
                        startActivity(intent1);
                       Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,response,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    else{
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,response, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss ();
                    Log.e("Volly Error", error.toString());


                }
            }
            ){
                @Override
                protected Map<String,String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                    Map<String,String> params=new HashMap<String,String>();
                    params.put("email",str_email);
                    params.put("password",str_password);
                    return params;
                }
            };
            RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(LoginActivity.this);
            requestQueue.add(request);
        }
```

Below is the logcat

```
com.android.volley.TimeoutError
```

After the android volley 1.2.0 update . Login and Sign-up in my app automatically stopped working.
In logcat it shows timeout error
Can somebody please help.

Comment: Did you double check, that you can reach the service and that there is no firewall or any other connectivity issue? Also you need to use `https`.

Comment: Thank you for your help sir. But I am still confused what should I change in the code or anywhere else